# Mixin for Icon using Font and Class

Tags: css, less

I have the following global CSS in my project to use icons with a font:

```
[data-icon]:before {
  font-family: 'Icons_Font';
  content: attr(data-icon);
  speak: none;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  text-transform: none;
  line-height: 1;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

[class*="icon-"] {
  font-family: 'Icons_Font';
  speak: none;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  text-transform: none;
  line-height: 1;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
```

Is it possible to create two mixins so I place this code in my Base CSS code?

I would like to pass to the mixin the name of the font-family, e.g., Icons_Font or other.

Everything is the same ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible.

Something like this for your two mixins:

```
.font-data-icon(@font-family){
 [data-icon]:before {
  font-family: @font-family;
  content: attr(data-icon);
  speak: none;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  text-transform: none;
  line-height: 1;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
 }
}
.icon-class(@font-family){
 [class*="icon-"] {
  font-family: @font-family;
  speak: none;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  text-transform: none;
  line-height: 1;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
 }
}
```

and then you can call the mixins, passing the desired arguments:

```
.font-data-icon('Icons_Font');
.icon-class('Icons_Font');
```

or just one mixin for both, if the properties stay the same in both:

```
.font-mixin(@font-family){
  font-family: @font-family;
  speak: none;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  text-transform: none;
  line-height: 1;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
```

and call it twice like this in the two rules:

```
[data-icon]:before {
   .font-mixin('Icons_Font');
}
[class*="icon-"] {
   .font-mixin('Icons_Font');
}
```

the CSS output in both cases would be:

```
[data-icon]:before {
  font-family: 'Icons_Font';
  content: attr(data-icon);
  speak: none;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  text-transform: none;
  line-height: 1;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
[class*="icon-"] {
  font-family: 'Icons_Font';
  speak: none;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  text-transform: none;
  line-height: 1;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
```

Comment: I can't use the second approach because there is a difference between the data-icon and class: "content: attr(data-icon);" ... But the first suggestion is fine.